# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'No entry is registered for key 'Zend_Db''

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I have been searching to find a fix for this error.. none found yet.  Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'No entry is registered for key 'Zend_Db'' in /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/.../play/library/Zend/Registry.php:145
Stack trace:
#0 /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/..../play/application/Model/Artist/Db.php(47): Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Db')
#1 /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/..../play/application/Modules/Default/Controllers/IndexController.php(64): Model_Artist_Db->__construct()
#2 /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/.../play/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(132): IndexController->init()
#3 /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/.../play/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(261): Zend_Controller_Action->__construct(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http), Array)
#4 /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/.../play/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(936): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#5 /hermes/bosoraw in /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/..../play/library/Zend/Registry.php on line 145
```

here is my all codes

**Bootstrap.php**

```
  /** 
     * @access Public
     * return void
    */
    public static function setupRegistry() 
    {
        self::$registry = new Zend_Registry(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
        Zend_Registry::setInstance(self::$registry);
    }

        /** 
 * @access Public
 * return void
*/
public static function setupDatabase()
{

    if ( self::$registry->configuration->installed) {

        $dbConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini( self::$root . '/application/Configs/Database.ini', 'default' );

        $db = Zend_Db::factory($dbConfig); 


        // profiler
        $profiler = new Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug('All DB Queries');
        $profiler->setEnabled(true);

        // Attach the profiler to your db adapter
        $db->setProfiler($profiler);

        self::$registry->set('Zend_Db', $db);
    } 
}
```

**and Model/Artist/Db.php**

```
<?php

class Model_Artist_Db
{

    /* @access Public
     * @var object
     */
    private static $db      = null;

    /* @access Public
     * @var object
     */
    private static $cache   = null;

    /* @access Public
     * @var object
     */
    private static $config  = null;


    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @access Public
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$db = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Db');

        $moduleConfig = Zend_Registry::get('moduleConfig');
        self::$config = $moduleConfig->module->artist;

        $cacheDir = Zend_Registry::get('siteRootDir') .'/data/cache/' .self::$config->cache->dir;

        $frontendOptions = array('lifetime' => self::$config->cache->lifetime, 'automatic_serialization' => self::$config->cache->serialization);
        $backendOptions  = array('cache_dir' => $cacheDir);

        self::$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $page
     * param String $alpha
     * @return Object
     */
    public function getAllArtists($page,$alpha)
    {

        if ( !empty($alpha)) {
            $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from("artist")
                ->where('artist LIKE ?', $alpha.'%')
                ->order('artist')
                ->group('artist');
        } else {
            $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from("artist")
                ->order('artist')
                ->group('artist');
        }         

         $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($sql);

         $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

         $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(self::$config->perPage);

         $paginator->setPageRange(self::$config->pageRange);

        return $paginator;
    }


     /**
     * @access Public
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getArtistGenres()
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
            ->from(array('a' => 'artist'), array('artist_id', 'artist', 'genres'));

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param String $name
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getArtistByName($name)
    {
        $cacheId = self::_clean($name);

        if(!$result = self::$cache->load('getArtistByName_'.$cacheId) ) {
            $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from("artist")
                    ->where('artist = ?', $name);

            $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

            /** save cache */
            if(self::$config->cache->enable == 1) {
                self::$cache->save($result, 'getArtistByName_'.$cacheId);
            }
        }    

        return $result;       
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getArtistByID($artistId)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from("artist")
                ->where('artist_id = ?', $artistId);

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param String $guid
     * @return Int
     */
    public function getArtistIdByGuid($guid)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from(array('a' => 'artist'), array('artist_id') )
                ->where('a.artist_guid = ?', $guid);

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        return $result['artist_id'];
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param String $guid
     * @return Bool
     */
    public function checkArtistImage($guid){
        $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from(array('ai' => 'artist_images'), array('id') )
                ->where('ai.guid = ?', $guid);

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        if($result['id'] > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getArtistAlbums($artistId)
    {

        if(!$result = self::$cache->load('getArtistAlbums_'.$artistId) ) {
            $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from(array("al" =>"album"), array('album_id','image','released', 'title','track_count', 'playtime_secs', 'play_count', 'date_added'))
                    ->join(array("ar" => "artist"), 'al.artist_id = ar.artist_id', array('artist'))
                    ->where('al.artist_id = ?', $artistId)
                    ->order('al.title')
                    ->group('al.title');

            $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

            /** save cache */
            if(self::$config->cache->enable == 1) {
                self::$cache->save($result, 'getArtistAlbums_'.$artistId);
            }
        }
        return$result;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @param String $artistAlbum
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getAlbum($artistId, $artistAlbum)
    {
        $cacheId = self::_clean($artistId . $artistAlbum);        

        if(!$result = self::$cache->load('getAlbum_'.$cacheId) ) {

            $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from(array("al" =>"album"), array('album_id','image','released', 'title','track_count', 'playtime_secs', 'play_count', 'date_added'))
                    ->join(array("ar" => "artist"), 'al.artist_id = ar.artist_id', array('artist'))
                    ->where('al.artist_id = ?', $artistId)
                    ->where('al.title = ?', $artistAlbum);

            $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();  

            /** save cache */
            if(self::$config->cache->enable == 1) {
                self::$cache->save($result, 'getAlbum_'.$cacheId);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $page
     * @param Int $albumId
     * @return Object
     */
    public function getAlbumTracks($page,$albumId)
    {
         $sql = self::$db->select()
            ->from("files")
            ->where('album = ?', $albumId)
            ->order('track');       

         $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($sql);

         $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

         $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(self::$config->perPage);

         $paginator->setPageRange(self::$config->pageRange);

        return $paginator;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $page
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return Object
     */
    public function getTopPlayedTracks($page,$artistId)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from(array('f' => 'files'), array('file_id','filename','title','playtime_seconds','play_count'))
                ->join(array('a' => 'album'), 'f.album = a.album_id', array('title as album'))
                ->where('f.artist = ?', $artistId)
                ->order('f.play_count DESC')
                ->order('f.title');

        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($sql);

        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(self::$config->perPage);

        $paginator->setPageRange(self::$config->pageRange);

        return $paginator;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $limit
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getTopPlayed($limit)
    {

        if(!$result = self::$cache->load('getTopPlayed') ) {
            $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from(array('ar' => 'artist'), array('artist', 'image', 'play_count', 'artist_id', 'date_added'))
                ->where('play_count > ?', 0)
                ->order('play_count DESC')
                ->limit($limit);

            $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetchAll();       

            /** get counts */
            for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {

                /** album Count */
                $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from('album', 'count(album_id) as album_count')
                    ->where('artist_id = ?', $result[$i]['artist_id']);
                $rs = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();
                $result[$i]['album_count'] = $rs['album_count'];

                /** track count */
                $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from('files', 'count(file_id) as track_count')
                    ->where('artist = ?', $result[$i]['artist_id']);
                $rs = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();
                $result[$i]['track_count'] = $rs['track_count'];

                /** Play Time */
                $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from('files', 'sum(playtime_seconds) as playtime')
                    ->where('artist = ?', $result[$i]['artist_id']);
                $rs = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();
                $result[$i]['playtime'] = $rs['playtime'];            
            }

            /** save cache */
            if(self::$config->cache->enable == 1) {
                self::$cache->save($result, 'getTopPlayed');
            }
        } 

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $limit
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getNewArtists($limit)
    {
        if(!$result = self::$cache->load('getNewArtists') ) {

            $sql = self::$db->select()
                ->from(array('ar' => 'artist'), array('artist', 'image', 'date_added','play_count', 'artist_id'))
                ->order('date_added DESC')
                ->group('artist')
                ->limit($limit);

            $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

            /** get counts */
            for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {

                /** album Count */
                $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from('album', 'count(album_id) as album_count')
                    ->where('artist_id = ?', $result[$i]['artist_id']);
                $rs = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();
                $result[$i]['album_count'] = $rs['album_count'];

                /** track count */
                $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from('files', 'count(file_id) as track_count')
                    ->where('artist = ?', $result[$i]['artist_id']);
                $rs = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();
                $result[$i]['track_count'] = $rs['track_count'];

                /** Play Time */
                $sql = self::$db->select()
                    ->from('files', 'sum(playtime_seconds) as playtime')
                    ->where('artist = ?', $result[$i]['artist_id']);
                $rs = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();
                $result[$i]['playtime'] = $rs['playtime'];            
            }


            /** save cache */
            if(self::$config->cache->enable == 1) {
                self::$cache->save($result, 'getNewArtists');
            }   

        }        

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $page
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return Object
     */
    public function getArtistImages($page,$artistId)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
            ->from(array('a' => 'artist_images'), array('id','artist_id','title','dateadded','votes','image'))
            ->where('a.artist_id = ?', $artistId);

        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($sql);

        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(self::$config->perPage);

        $paginator->setPageRange(self::$config->pageRange);

        return $paginator;        
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $imageId
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getArtistImageById($imageId)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
            ->from(array('ai' => 'artist_images'), array('id','guid','artist_id','title','url','dateadded','image'))
            ->where('ai.id = ?', $imageId);

         $result = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Array $simularArtist
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getSimularArtists($simularArtist)
    {
        $cacheId = self::_clean(serialize($simularArtist));

        if(!$array = self::$cache->load('getSimularArtists_'.$cacheId) ) {

            $array = array();

            $c = 0;

            for($i = 0; $i < count($simularArtist['similar']); $i++) {

                $name = urlencode($simularArtist['similar'][$i]['name']);

                $artist = self::getArtistByName($name);

                if( !empty($artist) ) {
                    $array[$c]['artist'] = $artist['artist'];
                    $array[$c]['image']  = $artist['image'];
                    $array[$c]['match']  = $simularArtist['similar'][$i]['match'];

                    $c++;
                } 
            }

            /** save cache */
            if(self::$config->cache->enable == 1) {
                self::$cache->save($array, 'getSimularArtists_'.$cacheId);
            }       

        }    

        return $array;
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getArtistCount()
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
            ->from(array('ar' => 'artist'), array('count(artist_id) as artist_count'));

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        return $result['artist_count'];
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return Void
     */
    public function incrementAlbumCount($artistId)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
            ->from(array('a' => 'artist'), array('album_count'))
            ->where('artist_id = ?', $artistId);

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        $data = array(
            'album_count' => $result['album_count'] + 1
        );

        self::$db->update('artist', $data, 'artist_id = ' . $artistId);

    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return Void
     */
    public function incrementTrackCount($artistId)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select()
            ->from(array('a' => 'artist'), array('track_count'))
            ->where('artist_id = ?', $artistId);

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        $data = array(
            'track_count' => $result['track_count'] + 1
        );

        self::$db->update('artist', $data, 'artist_id = ' . $artistId);
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return Void
     */
    public function incrementPlayCount($artistId)
    {
        $sql = self::$db->select() 
            ->from(array('a' => 'artist'), array('play_count'))
            ->where('a.artist_id = ?', $artistId);

        $result  = self::$db->query($sql)->fetch();

        $data = array(
            'play_count' => $result['play_count'] + 1
        );

        self::$db->update('artist', $data, 'artist_id = ' . $artistId );
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Array $data
     * @param Int $artistId
     * @return Void
     */
    public function updateArtist($data, $artistId)
    {
         self::$db->update('artist', $data, 'artist_id = ' . $artistId );
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Array $data
     * @param Int $imageId
     * @return Void
     */
    public function updateArtistImage($data, $imageId)
    {
        self::$db->update('artist_images', $data, 'id = ' . $imageId );
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Array $data
     * @return Int
     */
    public function newArtist($data)
    {
        self::$db->insert('artist', $data);
        return self::$db->lastInsertId();                                                                
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Array $data
     * @return Int
     */
    public function createNewImage($data)
    {
        self::$db->insert('artist_images', $data);
        return self::$db->lastInsertId();   
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param Int $imageId
     * @return Void
     */
    public function removeArtistImage($imageId)
    {
        self::$db->delete('artist_images', 'id = '.$imageId);
    }


    /**
     * @access Public
     * @param String $string
     * @return String
     */
    private function _clean($string)
    {
        return md5($string);
    }


}
```

**Databass Config file**

```
[default]
adapter = "pdo_mysql"
params.host = "sitename.ipagemysql.com"
params.dbname = "play"
params.username = "play"
params.password = "123456"
```

Comment: you have to provide more code like how did you created the connection (probably in Bootstrap.php) and how did you called that connection in Model/Artist/Db.php

Comment: How is setupDatabase() called in your bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Where and when do you call setupDatabase function written in your bootstrap file?

Don't forget that only method prepend by _init prefix are called in this bootstrap file. Your static method (why static ?) are probably never called.

That's why you have no entry in your registry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry boss this script made by some developer..this is a music playlist script and i try to get support from the script developer but i think his gone...now im here for help i really don't no about it....